# How to execute python script inside the Kubernetes pod as an initial trigger

Tags: python-3.x, docker, kubernetes, devops, google-kubernetes-engine

I am having a python code running inside the Kubernetes POD, To trigger that I have another python script that runs in the background with "nohup".This nohup python script reads input data from pubsub and passes that to python application to process.

As of now I am executing this script manually whenever I deploy the POD, Now I am trying to include this execution also as a part of POD deployment.

I tried to implement this both, in Dockerfile as CMD and also in the Kubernetes deployment file, But it's not triggering.

How can I make that script run in the background for every restart and deployment?

**Dockerfile:**

`CMD ["/bin/bash", "/auto/pubsub.py"]`

`CMD ["nohup", "python3", "./auto/pubsub.py", "&"]`

`CMD ["python3", "/auto/pubsub.py"]`

**Kubernetes deployment file**

`command: ["python3","/auto/pubsub.py", "while true; do sleep 1000; done"]`

Comment: It sounds like you want to run this as a Kubernetes Job? Alternatively as an Init-Container?

Comment: A container only runs one process, and in this setup the Kubernetes `command:` overrides the Dockerfile `CMD` (and there only the last one has an effect).  But this setup sounds a little overcomplicated to me; can you make the Python code that attaches to the pub/sub engine directly call the Python function that processes the data, in a single Python application?

Comment: @Jonas
No I am running as a deployment,I tried to run as a init container and startup probe but in both places i am getting below error.

```  /auto/pubsub.py: line 18:  No such file or directory
python3: can't open file 'pubsub.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory```

Comment: @DavidMaze
Previously I execute these scripts manually now I am trying to execute them inside the POD as a microservice, But failing to trigger the initial script.